# Make multiple plots from 3D matrix, of data inside given polygon

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a 420*940*12 matrix (the value of each grid ranges from 0-100) and I want to plot data only inside polygon `S`, with `lat` (420*1) and `lon` (940*1) as grid references.

We can create a single plot of only points without its values (0-100):

```
S = shaperead(polygon);
N = length(S);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(lon,lat);
data= test;
for k = 1:N
    idx =  insidepoly(X(:),Y(:),S(k).X,S(k).Y);
    hold on
    plot(X(idx), Y(idx), 'r*')
end
```

But this figure is only showing the points not its values (0-100)
And the output is something like this:

[image: one plot]

But I have to plot multiple data together, lets say 12 months of a year so, how can I make 12 plots together according to values (0-100) as in the below figure?

[image: month plots]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivwqq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible solution is to use montage, see here:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');
img = repmat(img,1,1,1,6);
montage(img)
```

Comment: Main query is to plot points with respect their values (0-100), which I could not figure out. Made minor edits in question and replace the required figure to make more clear question. After that montage/subplot and other function to grid of multiple plots.

Comment: So we could use example data of one image to play with

Comment: I think so, we could make attempt to make grid plot after getting required result for single image first.